# Существует ли комбинация операторов LIKE и IN в условии запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

В SQL (к сожалению) часто приходится пользоваться `LIKE` из-за того, что в используемых БД нарушены почти все правила нормализации. Не могу пока это изменить, но это и не относится к вопросу.

Кроме того, часто использую такое условие:

```
WHERE something in (1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21)
```

в SQL запросах для улучщения их читаемости и расширяемости.

Существует ли возможность объединить эти два оператора без написания сложных подзапросов?

Хотелось бы нечто такое же простое как:

```
WHERE something LIKE ('bla%', '%foo%', 'batz%')`
```

вместо такого:

```
WHERE something LIKE 'bla%'
OR something LIKE '%foo%'
OR something LIKE 'batz%'
```

В основном работаю с *SQL Server* и *Oracle*, но будут интересны также решения в других реляционных СУБД.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/3014940/6571020

Answer (score 6):

Такое решение полностью стандартно, работало, и будет работать на любой СУБД:

```sql
create table patterns (pattern varchar (32));
insert into patterns values ('bla%');
insert into patterns values ('%foo%');
insert into patterns values ('batz%');

select something
from tab
where exists (
    select 1
    from patterns
    where something like pattern
);
```

Вывод:

```
SOMETHING 
----------
blaaaa
xxfooo
batzzz
```

Вместо таблицы можно использовать любую конструкцию способную вернуть строки, такие как например: представление, табличные функции, коллекции, см. ответы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1014692/217579) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1014482/217579).

Comment: Разве это не будет сильно медленно? Мне казалось, что перечисление с OR будет оптимальнее...

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, не должно, уж во всяком случае не сильно медленней. Конкретно конечно надо смотреть по планам и на реальных данных.

Answer (score 4):

В *Oracle* для этого есть оператор [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19):

```sql
select something
from tab
where regexp_like (something, '(^bla|foo|^batz)')
;
```

Вывод:

```sql
SOMETHING 
----------
blaaaa
xxfooo
batzzz
```

Запрос с оператором `OR` как в вопросе будет конечно производительней.
Поэтому, если производительность главный критерий, то попробуйте альтернативое решение с использованием коллекций:

```sql
create or replace type strlist is table of varchar2 (4000);
/
select something
from tab
where exists (
    select 1
    from table (strlist ('bla%', '%foo%', 'batz%')) t
    where something like t.column_value
);
```

---

Тестовые данные:

```sql
create table tab as
with data (something) as (
    select 'blaaaa' from dual union all
    select 'xxfoooo' from dual union all
    select 'batzzz' from dual
) select * from data;
```

Answer (score 4):

В *SQL Server* (если вести речь о комбинировании нескольких `LIKE` для констант-литералов) стоит сравнить комбинирование через `OR` с Left Semi Join альтернативой

```
SELECT t.something
FROM tab t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('bla%'), ('%foo%'), ('batz%'))p (pattern)
    WHERE t.something LIKE p.pattern
    );
```

При прочих равных, вариант с `OR` скорее всего будет предпочтительнее по производительности, но эти два варианта не одновременно пересекают порог, при котором оптимизатор может решить использовать параллелизм, так что `OR`-вариант может и проиграть в производительности.

Есть ещё вариант с использованием функции `STRING_SPLIT` (начиная с SQL Server 2016)

```
SELECT t.something
FROM tab t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('bla%|%foo%|batz%', '|') spl
    WHERE t.something LIKE spl.value
    )
```

Синтаксически и функционально схож с альтернативой на основе `VALUES`, но менее производителен и обладает дополнительными ограничениями (из-за символа разделителя).

Однако, если ставить целью лаконичность кода при дальнейшем использовании, то с помощью `STRING_SPLIT` можно создать функцию-обёртку, в которую можно поместить `WHERE EXISTS` (для применения к таблицам лучше использовать встраиваемую табличную функцию)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LikeAny
(
    @value nvarchar(4000),
    @likePatterns nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT CAST(1 as bit) AS IsLikeAny
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@likePatterns, '|') spl
        WHERE @value like spl.value
        )
GO
```

С таблицей потом использовать так

```
SELECT t.something
FROM tab t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.LikeAny(t.something, 'bla%|%foo%|batz%') la
```

Для скалярного применения удобнее будет скалярная функция

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LikeAnyS
(
    @value nvarchar(4000),
    @likePatterns nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN IIF(
        EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@likePatterns, '|') spl
        WHERE @value like spl.value
        ), 1, 0);
END
GO
```

Использовать можно так

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(100);
SET @string = 'aafooaa';
SELECT dbo.LikeAnyS(@string, 'bla%|%foo%|batz%');
```

Встроенного REGEXP функционала в SQL Server нет, но можно его добавить с помощью CLR-функции, которая по производительности, вероятно, позволит приблизиться к `OR`-варианту, а по лаконичности - к `REGEXP_LIKE`-варианту в Oracle

```
SELECT something
FROM tab
WHERE CLR.RxLike(something, '(^bla|foo|^batz)') = 1;
```

Если на столбце есть полнотекстовый индекс, то вместо `LIKE 'bla%'` и `LIKE 'batz%'` можно воспользоваться функцией `CONTAINS`

```
SELECT something
FROM tab
WHERE CONTAINS(something, '"bla*" or "batz*")');
```

---

Для `LIKE '%foo%'` в SQL Server нельзя построить эквивалент с помощью `CONTAINS`, т.к. `LIKE` найдёт *foo* в любой части *строки*, но `CONTAINS` так искать не может, `CONTAINS` может найти *слово* (`CONTAINS(.., 'foo')`) или *начало слова* (`CONTAINS(.., '"foo*"')`), или *словоформы* (`CONTAINS(.., 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, foo)')`).

В этом смысле, на мой взгляд, `LIKE` всё-таки ближе к REGEX по функциональности, чем к полнотекстовому поиску.

Comment: Здорово, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Нет, комбинации операторов `LIKE` и `IN` в стндарте SQL не существует, и вряд ли она появится.

В основном причина кроется в том, что поиск по `LIKE` паттерну, даже если колонка индексирована стандартным *B-TREE* индексом, может быть [крайне неэффективным](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224726/6571020) в плане производительности.

Рекомендованная альтернатива - FTS (*full text search*) с оператором `CONTAINS`. Многие СУБД уже включили поддержку FTS, хотя синтаксис может несколько отличаться.

**Пример для *Oracle***

Для [тестовых данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1014482/217579) необходимо создать индекс с типом `CONTEXT`:

```
create index idx_something on tab (something) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

И такой запрос:

```sql
select something 
from tab t
where contains (t.something, 'bla% or %foo% or batz%') > 0;
```

Даст желаемый результат:

```
SOMETHING 
----------
blaaaa
xxfooo
batzzz
```

Подробнее см.: [Oracle Text SQL Statements and Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/oracle-text-SQL-statements-and-operators.html#GUID-4775F5FE-4569-4DF4-A7CA-B20EC6880CAB).