# Как забрать данные по ключевым словам из колонки text

Tags: sql

Всем привет. Загружаю данные парсинга  в бд и хочу забирать с колонки text только те посты которые которые соответствуют ключевым словам.
То есть если есть ключевое слово в посте то забираем его полностью. Как можно это реализовать если требуется 20 ключевых слов?

для одного слова конструкция вот такая:

SELECT post_id, text FROM vk_post WHERE status = False AND text LIKE '%Привет%'

P.S. Требуется искать не 1 слово из 20 а, пробегаться по всем ключевым словам

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014465/%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-like-%d0%b8-in-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: Откуда появляются ключевые слова? это произвольный ввод, или существует предопределённый список (в какой-то таблице)? Во втором случае однозначно оптимальным решением является предрасчёт.

Comment: @Akina Ключевые слова это произвольный ввод

Comment: Ну тогда смотри в сторону полнотекстового поиска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил этот вопрос с помощью такой конструкции:

```
SELECT post_id, text FROM vk_post WHERE status = False 
AND (text LIKE '%слово1%' OR text like '%слово2%' OR text like '%слово3%'
```